# How can I create a card using Stripe and Node,js

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe as a payment method in my project using Node.js. I'm following [the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/create?lang=node) to archive this.

What I need is to create a card with the following information: credit card number, person's name, expiration date and security code.

This is my code:

```js
const createCard = (customer, cardInfo) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    stripe.customers.createSource(
      customer,
      {
        source: {
          object: 'card',
          ...cardInfo
        }
      },
      (err, card) => {
        if (err) {
          debug('There was an error while creating a new card')
          reject(err)
        }
        debug(card)
        resolve(card)
      }
    )
  })
}
```

The `cardInfo` object looks like this:

```
{
  "number": "4242424242424242",
  "exp_month": "11",
  "exp_year": "2021",
  "cvc": "123",
  "name": "My name"
}
```

This is what I get in the callback answer:

`Sending credit card numbers directly to the Stripe API is generally unsafe. We suggest you use test tokens that map to the test card you are using, see https://stripe.com/docs/testing."`

I'm using my develpment api key.

Comment: See [the tokens tab (next to card numbers) here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#cards). You can then replace the second argument to `createSource` to use the token instead of a card object; eg: `createSource(customer, { source: "tok_visa" })`.

Comment: So there's no way to test with real credit cards, names, etc? I guess I could check if NODE_ENV is set to production to make the switch. Thaks!

Comment: Well if your server is actually handling credit card numbers, this is bad. That is what stripe is warning you against, since there are PCI compliance concerns in that case. Ideally you should tokenize the card *on the client side* and then send *only* the token to your server, which is then converted into a source object and attached to the customer.

Comment: No, Im dont want to store credit cards numbers in my db. I want to use them to create a Card (stripe) and attach it to a customer. Should I continue with this approach or should I create a token for the card in the client side?

Comment: According to the docs `Tokens cannot be stored or used more than once. To store card or bank account information for later use, you can create Customer objects or Custom accounts.` so this won't work for me since I have to store credit cards info to future payments.

Comment: Tokens can indeed only be used once, but that doesn't mean what you think. For that one use of a token, you can attach it to the customer as a source. At that point *the token cannot be used again* **but** *the source object which you created from it can be reused!!!*.

Comment: Also to give a clear answer on your other comment, *do not continue with your current approach*, you must tokenize the cards on the client. If you don't, PCI compliance will become a *big* problem for you.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using Stripe.js and Elements (a client-side Javascript library) to tokenize cards on your webpage, and then using the tokens Stripe gives you, on your server-side Node.js code (to either charge them or save for future use).

https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment#web-collect-card-details

Passing card details directly to your server is highly not recommended as it has much higher PCI compliance burden on your integration.

Comment: Can i create a creditcard token without also making a payment? I just want to save the cards and attach them to my customerIDs for later usage.

Comment: @akko Yes, creating a credit card token and creating a charge (payment) are two separate api actions in stripe. Creating a token does not charge the card it was made from. Your flow should be: *create token on client -> send token to server -> server creates new source on customer using the token*. The card will not be charged during any of those steps.